# WSO2 Cloud adapters

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I went thorough the features of WSO2 ESB. I noticed WSO2 Coud Connectors like Twitter, LinkedIn ..

I would like to know about any documents, wiki which supports this. I have the Auth Keys from Twitter. I want to do a simple twitter integration using WSO2 ESB.

Please share your thoughts.

Regards,
Guru
@gnanagurus

Answer (score 0):

This is a new feature that will be released with WSO2 ESB 4.5.0. You can do 3rd party API integration very easily with this new feature. For example once the Twitter Connector Library is deployed in the ESB , you can feed the relevant OAuth keys directly and connect to Twitter Cloud seamlessly. Currently there are no publicly available docs. But please await we will be releasing this documentation soon with upcoming releases.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the documentation on connectors from [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/ESB+Connectors). Twitter specific documentation can be found [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Twitter+Connector).